# Difference between adding functions to $scope and this in directive controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When going through egghead video, the one about [Directive to directive communication](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication) suggests we use controller to add functions to 'this' object and access it from other directives.

The full code used in the video: [Adding functions to this object](http://jsfiddle.net/manojpcw/Efaw4/)

The relevant controller code is as follows:

```
controller: function($scope){
        $scope.abilities = [];
        this.addStrength = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Strength");
        }

        this.addSpeed = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Speed");
        }

        this.addFlight = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Flight");
        }
    },
```

I was wondering instead of adding functions to 'this' why not add it to the $scope itself especially when we are using isolated scope?

Code adding functions to $scope: [Adding functions to $scope](http://jsfiddle.net/manojpcw/PGNKF/)

The relevant controller code is as follows:

```
controller: function($scope){
        $scope.abilities = [];
        $scope.addStrength = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Strength");
        };

        $scope.addSpeed = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Speed");
        };

        $scope.addFlight = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Flight");
        };
    },
```

Or why have the controller function at all. Why can not we use the link function to achieve the same result?

Adding functions to $scope in the link function: [Using link funtciont instead of controller](http://jsfiddle.net/manojpcw/BLXzK/)

The relevant controller and link function is as follows:

```
controller: function($scope){
        $scope.abilities = [];
        $scope.addStrength = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Strength");
        };

        $scope.addSpeed = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Speed");
        };

        $scope.addFlight = function(){
            $scope.abilities.push("Flight");
        };
    },
```

I am pretty sure there is valid reason to use controller and this object. I am not able to understand why.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that you *can* expose functions in the `link` function and get the same results. Directive controllers are a bit of an odd bird, but as I've written more complex directives, I've settled on pushing as much behavior into controllers and leaving DOM-related stuff in the `link` function. The reason why is:

- I can pass in a controller name instead of having the function inside my directive; things get cleaner IMO
- The controllers can expose public APIs used inside of sibling or related directives so you can have some interop and encourage SoC.
- You can isolate the controller testing apart from the directive compilation if you like.

I typically only introduce controllers when there are perhaps complex state transitions, external resources being handled (ie $http), or if reuse is a concern.

You should note that Angular 1.2 exposes 'controllerAs' on directives which allows you to directly consume the controller in directive templates and reduce a bit of the ceremony the $scope composition introduces.